# Facebook 3.0 on Android: Showing login dialog twice

Tags: android, facebook, permissions, dialog

I have an android applicatin that integrated with facebook.

I called openActiveSession to open up a session. Once the session opened, I request a publish stream using NewRequestPermission object.

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, Arrays.asList("publish_stream")); 
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(fbPublishRequestStateCallback);
```

I noticed that the openActiveSession will open up a login dialog but when it hits the NewPermissionsRequest part of the code, it opened up a login dialog again.

Does anyone know why it showed login dialog again after the first login dialog?

Comment: Is the text exactly the same in both dialogs? Having a new dialog popup when requesting new permissions is the expected behavior, since it needs to get the user to acknowledge that they're granting you additional permissions.

Comment: It asking me to login again.

Comment: Oh, are you talking about it opening up a webview dialog? Update your SDK to the latest 3.0.1 release, there's a fix there that addresses this issue.